# Is Logging Module's thread safety, thread safe on the network as well?

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

We are dumping log's into a single file with `timestamps` from multiple computers (`500`) and each entry is less than 4KB's. Python's logging module apparently handles the `locking` and guarantees `Thread-Safety`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#thread-safety

Thanks @user2357112 for your feedback, here are some more information:

> Are you using some sort of network-attached storage?

The storage is a network disk, which shares a writable `logfile.txt` that can be read/written.

> Are the computers logging things locally and synchronizing their log files somehow?

The computers not logging locally but ones they are finished, they are using the 'Logger' to write to the end of the `logfile.txt` that is shared

> How are log records from different computers ending up in the same file?

All of the computers are appending to `logfile.txt`

So What can go wrong writing to a single file? Or is it safe to use?

Comment: What do you mean, writing logs from multiple computers to the same file? We're going to need to know a lot more about how your networking is set up and how these computers are writing to the file.

Comment: They are writing using the `Logging` module of python? I even posted the link about it. The Network is in an intranet and each machine is probably writing a log every 2 hours...so no big load in general.. but can race conditions still appear?

Comment: Are you using some sort of network-attached storage? Is there a central computer receiving log messages from the network and logging them? Are the computers logging things locally and synchronizing their log files somehow? *How are log records from different computers ending up in the same file?* Just saying you're using the `logging` module doesn't tell us that.

Comment: That's usefull, i'm going to update my question to put those in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So What can go wrong writing to a single file? Or is it safe to use?

At best, the driver handling file access will lock the file exclusively to one process/user.  At worst, just because you're appending doesn't mean it will be sequential.  for example You mangled lines up with could end  like this.

Perhaps a better/safer approach is just something like `/myNas/logs/MMDDYYHH/workerPID.log` and then have a daily cleaner script merge all of these into a master.log file.  In an intermediate processing step, you could read each log, put it into a :memory: sqlite database, sort entries by date & time, and dump it into a consolidated `master.log`.

Alternatively if real time log monitoring is necessary, I believe Windows has equivalent tools like `watch` which can follow each file as it is written to disk.